# ESLint React-Router v4 - How to validate Match params props?

Tags: reactjs, eslint, react-router-v4

I'm using React-Router v4's [Match object](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/match) to pass down params to the next component. Where my Routing is like:

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact path="/" component={ExperimentListPage} />
  <Route path="/experiment/:experiment" component={ExperimentResultsPage} />
</Switch>
```

and my subcomponent looks like:

```
const ExperimentResultsPage = props => (
   <ExperimentResultsContainer experimentName={props.match.params.experiment} />
);

export default withRouter(ExperimentResultsPage);
```

And it all works as intended, however ESLint is really unhappy with me using `match.params.experiment` and it errors with `[eslint] 'match.params.experiment' is missing in props validation (react/prop-types)`

I saw in the React docs that I could use [`PropTypes.shape`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html) however my params object but I was hoping there is a better way especially because the Match object contains a lot of fields.

Is there a better way of adding your Match route object to the props validation? How would that look like? If not, am I missing some other approach that could help solve this?

Comment: This is a difficult one, as you said `Proptypes.shape` is not very practical with large complex objects. I would suggest just a plain `PropTypes.object`. It is not best practice (describing the shape of the object would be better) but it will quiet eslint

Comment: That did cross my mind. However React has you covered in that case as well -> `[eslint] Prop type `object` is forbidden (react/forbid-prop-types)` -> https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/forbid-prop-types.md

Comment: Things have changed since I have used it. As a last resort you can always `// eslint-disable-line (react/forbid-prop-types)`. Sorry i couldn't be of more help.

Comment: It's all good dude, thanks for trying!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I ran into something similar, eslint seems fine with only declaring what Im using as props and ignoring unused fields from match:

```
  match: PropTypes.shape({
    params: PropTypes.shape({
      experiment: PropTypes.string,
    }),
  }).isRequired,
```

Answer (score 0):

In a case whereby the component expects an object which has different keys of different shapes, the best way to go about that is to use `PropTypes.any` inside `objectOf` as below:

```
 match: PropTypes.objectOf(PropTypes.any),
```